# How to replace cycle('float: left', 'float: right') to use pure css?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, styling

Is there any way to replace `cycle('float: left', 'float: right')` so that instead of using `cycle` helper i could use pure css classes. I need to align divs left and right inside a single column. Using cycle leads to some difficulties with caching so it would be better to use static styling instead.

```
<div class="userCards">
    <div class="singleCard <%= cycle 'cardLeft', 'cardRight' %>">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that `userCard` has fixed height, `overflow: hidden`  and `width: 48%`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a work for `nth-child()` selector:

```
.userCards .singleCard:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
}

.userCards .singleCard:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
}
```